# Laravel: How Can I Convert This Sql Statement to Eloquent or Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

How can I convert this Sql Statement to Eloquent or Query Builder

I have 4 tables;

```
Jobs
Stores
Users
Store_User
```

Each Store hasMany Jobs while Stores and Users have a ManyToMany relationship through store_user table. I want to fetch all jobs of the stores a user is assigned to.

Users are assigned to one or more stores through the `store_user` table. And multiple jobs can belongTo a store.

I need to be able to use a `$user->jobs` or something that can fetch the list of jobs belonging to the user based on the stores he/she is assigned to.

Here is the SQL Statement. I was using in PDO.

```
  SELECT * FROM jobs 
      INNER JOIN store_user 
      INNER JOIN stores 
      WHERE stores.id = store_user.store_id 
      AND store_user.store_id = jobs.store_id 
      AND store_user.user_id = 2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do your entities look like?

Comment: Hi @WilliamPerron, I tried to use midnightcowboycoder.com to convert the my Sql Statement to Laravel's and got this.

     DB::select(*) ->from(jobs) ->from(store_user) ->from(stores) ->where(stores.id, =, store_user.store_id) ->where(store_user.store_id, =, jobs.store_id) ->where(store_user.user_id, =, 2) ->get();

However, when I put it in my controller, I get this error saying   

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty (SQL: )

Comment: @Iotsonj you should add this code to the body of the question, not as a comment.

Comment: can you add the table schema for the 4 tables

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
            ->join('store_user','store_user.store_id','=','jobs.store_id')
            ->join('stores','stores.id','=','store_user.store_id')
            ->where('store_user.user_id', '=' ,2)
            ->get();
```